# Permission(s) to edit cases created by the user

Tags: wordpress, civicase, permissions

I want to restrict a role to be able to create cases in CiviCase and be able to edit them. The "*access my cases and activities*" permission allows the role to create cases, but not to add new activities to the case they created. "*Access all cases and activities*" permits the role to edit not just their cases, but every case.

In other words, I want the role to

- be able to create new cases
- be able to edit the cases the user created
- not be able to edit other's cases

Running CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Wordpress 4.3.1. Is there any way to achieve this at the moment?

edit: Could it be that this behaviour is a bug, and the "*access my cases and activities*" permission is supposed to do exactly what I want?

edit2: Updated to CiviCRM 4.6.9, and now it seems that the "*access my cases and activities*" permission allows the role to create and edit **all** cases and activities. I don't think this is the intended outcome though, as that would make "*Access all cases and activities*" useless.

Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: The permission access my cases and activities is to access the cases you are a manager of. Or I think it is. Last year I have struggled a lot with cases and permissions and there seems no fine tuning possible on this topic. So it is not really a bug but it could be a wishable feature.

Comment: That's how I understood it should be, and I would be fine with it. Problem is, on 4.6.8, this perm only wasn't enough to add activities to one's cases. With 4.6.9, it's the other extreme for me - able to edit all cases, manager or not.